# Dart using fold on nested data class to get sum of count

Tags: flutter, dart

Here i have multiple nested class data and i want to get sum of `SelectedProductServices.count`

my data class started with `OrderStructure` which that have a list as `SelectedProducts` and each of them have `SelectedProductServices` which count is here. now how can i use `fold` or `reduce` to get sum of them?

for example:

```
order.products.map((p)=>p.services.fold(0,(a,b)=>a!+b))
```

should return `600`

my code:

```dart
void main() {
     OrderStructure order = OrderStructure('test',<SelectedProducts>[
      SelectedProducts(
          1, <SelectedProductServices>[
        const SelectedProductServices(1, 100, 1),
        const SelectedProductServices(1, 500, 1),
      ]
      )
    ]);
  
    getSum();
}

void getSum(){
   return order.products.map((p)=>p.services.fold(0,(a,b)=>a!+b));
}

class OrderStructure {
  final String title;
  final List<SelectedProducts> products;

  const OrderStructure(this.title, this.products);
}

class SelectedProducts {
  final int id;
  final List<SelectedProductServices> services;

  SelectedProducts(this.id, this.services);
  @override
  bool operator ==(other) => other is SelectedProducts && other.id == id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class SelectedProductServices {
  final int id;
  final int count;
  final int cost;

  const SelectedProductServices(this.id, this.count, this.cost);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have nested list, you'd have to fold twice to get a single value:

```
int getSum(){
   int sum(int a, SelectedProductServices s) => a + s.count;
   return order.products.map((p) => p.services.fold(0, sum)).fold(0, (a,b) => a + b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
int getSum(){
     return order.products.map((p) => p.services.fold(0, (int a, b) => a + b.count)).first;
}
```

Comment: This would only return the sum for the first product, since you have added `first` at the end. You'd need another `fold` for the total sum.

Comment: You are rigth @TmKVU, thanks for pointing it out